# Command not found when In chroot

Tags: arch-linux, chroot, arm, mobile, arm64

Im currently Porting Arch Linux to My phone and I am trying to set up the rootfs properly - have it installed to an external scdard and am using busybox to chroot into it with

```
busybox chroot /data/ local/mnt sh
```

I can see pacman exists when I search for it:

```
/usr/bin # type -a pacman returns

/sbin/pacman
```

but whenever I try to install the base system with:

`pacman -S base-devel 1lightdm xorg-xinit xfce4 networkmanager --needed` I
get

```
sh: pacman: not found
```

Comment: Does your chroot PATH include /sbin?

Comment: @roaima   my path looks pretty normal: /su/bin:/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/ su/xbin:/system/xbin

Comment: What does `/sbin/pacman ...` show.

Comment: The shell will return "not found" for numerous reasons. As mentioned, try running the command manually with full path and also find the file in the filesystem and examine it. It might be a script that's not working (many reasons for this), might not be executable, incompatible architecture, missing libraries, who knows. If you can, try `ldd /sbin/pacman` and look for missing stuff. Also try running `ldconfig` to refresh your library cache.

Comment: @CR.  sh: ldd: not found is what I get

Comment: @waltinator it exists , and shows the full list of binaries...

Comment: How did you install Arch on the SD card? What is `busyboxchroot`? Is it different than `busybox chroot`? Because I don't understand the extra parameter being passed.

Comment: @CR. I am indeed using busybox chroot - I just forgot to add the space during formatting this question. Iinstalled arch by formattting an sdcard to mbr ,  then adding a linux filesystem , then formatting it to ext4. I then extracted the rootfs into It. I am using a superuser shell into my phone , where I have mounted It using mkdir -p /data/local/mnt && busybox mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /data/local/mnt

Comment: @CR. I have all necesary files mounted too - with                                                             `# busybox mount -o bind /dev /data/local/mnt/dev`
`# busybox mount -o bind /dev/pts /data/local/mnt/dev/pts`
`# busybox mount -t proc none /data/local/mnt/proc`
`# busybox mount -t sysfs none /data/local/mnt/sys`

Comment: Where did the rootfs come from? It seems like something is wrong like missing libraries or incompatible binaries. Does `ls` work? Or `cat`, etc? Those commands have very few dependencies.

Comment: @CR. both cat and ls work , I got my rootfs from here https://archlinuxarm.org/about/downloads and selected the generic / multi platform armv8 rootfs

Answer (score 0):

I did the following on my Arm7 phone:

```bsh
mkfs.ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1
mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /data/local/mnt
cd /data/local/mnt
curl -O http://fl.us.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz
tar xvpf ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz
chroot /data/local/mnt
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf && echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf
pacman -Sy
# works!
```

Comment: Thanks for this , I am suspecting a architecture comparability issue , - the device I am doing this on is a  Huawei p9 Lite (2016) - and everywhere I search - Im told it's using armV8-a

Comment: when i do `busybox chroot /data/local/mnt` i get `chroot: can't execute '/su/bin/sush': No such file or directory`

Comment: @BilalAhmed I believe the systemless busybox tries to use sush as its default shell but your other method of `busybox chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/bash` should work. Another thing you can try is something like `chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/pacman -Sy` to see if pacman is able to run at all.

Comment: yes I had the same Idea , all commands were defaulting to `sush` - but when I try to do `busybox chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/bash` I get `chroot: can't execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`